# Stack overflow -question asked yesterday says asked Today!

Tags: support, time

[image: Bug Report screenshot]

Please find the screenshot for the details.Here i have asked a question yesterday(17-April-2014).When i reopen the question link today (18-Aril-2014)([How to Update and sync a Database tables at exactly same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126559/how-to-update-and-sync-a-database-tables-at-exactly-same-time?noredirect=1#comment35370456_23126559)) looking for an answer i found details on right hand side of the screen saying **Asked:Today Views:21**
**Please have a look at system time 11:00AM its TODAY!! and the question was asked yesterday**

Isn't that a bug?
Though i didnt get answer for my question!! that made me to look at these!

Comment: I'm guessing it says “today” until 24 hours have passed. At this time, only 22 hours have passed.

Comment: IIRC 'today', 'yesterday' is only relevant for the timezone where the Stack Exchange Team is based. here in Australia, 'Today' seems to roll over to 'Yesterday' at around 2pm AEST. At least, that's been my observation

Comment: This is because Windows XP is no longer a supported operating system. Y2K +14.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The day for a question starts from the time it was posted, so it changes to yesterday after 24 hours have passed since the question was asked.

It's not dependent on the calendar day of the local or server time.

Comment: simple answer solves my doubt.But user experience matters!!!.

Comment: I know I'm stating the obvious here but this is just flat out bad logic.  "Today" is not defined as "within the last 24 hours".  "Today" means on or after  12:00AM (my local time) of the PRESENT day that I'm visiting this site.  I understand it can be a matter of designers choice but that goes against any definition of "today" that I've ever heard of.  Can someone please explain further?

Comment: @jaredbaszler It might not fit the definition of a 'Bug', but it's certainly a design error. You can't just change the definition of words to suit your design.

Comment: Why not just showing the timestamp the question was posted and this problem would be gone...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you go by *the server time*, which you can find here:

[image]

Note, the system time is GMT 0 (UTC), in order to approximate a day for the site in your time zone, you'll need to find your GMT offset and establish a 0:00 reference point (e.g. 18:00 is 0:00 server time)

It's a common misunderstanding.

Comment: @mmu: people sometimes downvote when it's common enough that a search would easily find the question. Having said that, the Meta Stack Overflow split has made things a bit more difficult to find -- for now, you might also want to take a look at [metase].

Comment: but the logic for changing post status from today yesterday not depends on the server time or day change.

Comment: The relative dates are actually *not* based on UTC; they are just relative to the *post time*. Less than 24 hours ago? 'today'. 24 hours or more, but less than 28 hours? 'yesterday', etc.

Comment: Yes, it is relative to the time the post was created (which is relative to the system time), but a good distinction to make.